# Calculating overlap between categorical variables in the same DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am working on my undergraduate thesis and I have a question about part of my code. I am trying to calculate the number of times each column pair in a `df` has the same value. The columns are all binary (0, 1).

The input has this format:

`df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]], columns = ["col1", "col2"])`

For instance, the number of times `col1` and `col2` had the same value in the snippet above is 3.

This is the code i have so far

```
bl1 = []
bl2 = []
overlap = []

for i in df.iterrows():
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        for k in range(j):
            a = df.iloc[j] 
            b = df.iloc[k]
            
            comparison_column = np.where(a == b)
            
            bl1.append(df.columns[j])            
            bl2.append(df.columns[k])
            overlap.append(len(comparison_column[0]))
```

After combining the lists into a `pd.Dataframe` the output looks like this

```
Base Learner 1 Base Learner 2  overlap
         col1         col2       2
```

I know that the code does not work because I did a count in excel and got different results for the overlap count. I suspect that the loops fail to sum the number of times the pair was found across the `df.iterrows()` part but i do not know how to fix it. Please give me any suggestions you can. Thanks.

Comment: what's your expected output? Is it what QuangHoang has provided? Can you put that at end of your question similiar to how QuangHoang has put it in the answer?

Comment: i made edits as requested. thanks.

Comment: The expected output **should** reflect the sample data. Here your data has no `Rule40`. Also, please post sample/expected data as text, not pictures.

Comment: Thank you! For future, it's better to have text instead of an image for input and output, similar to how QuangHoang has provided, so that we can copy and paste ans use `pd.read_clipboard()` to read the data and test! Just an FYI :)

Comment: i made the edits once more lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try the magic matrix multiplication:

```
(df.T @ df) + ((1-df.T)@(1-df))
```

Output:

```
        Rule21  Rule22  Rule23  Rule24
Rule21       5       5       4       2
Rule22       5       5       4       2
Rule23       4       4       5       3
Rule24       2       2       3       5
```

---

Explanation: `df.T @ df` counts if corresponding cells in both columns are `1`. Similarly, `((1-df.T)@(1-df))` counts if both columns are `0`.

Comment: hello @Quang i dont understand how this line of code solves my issue. Can you please clarify it further? I added some more details in the question to phrase it better. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @igbobahaushe in the output I posted, for example, at row `Rule21` and column `Rule24` is the total number of overlapping in the original two columns. Does it answer your question?

Comment: thank you so much. looking back, i think what confused me was the devastating simplicity of your answer. best regards :)